# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un archivos de la carpeta RAW?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica con canciones alojadas en el raw, pero quiero saber si se puede acceder a algunas canciones no a todas que estan guardadas ahi.
El codigo que tengo hasta el momento llama a la carpeta raw y muestran todas las canciones en mi listview y desde alli lo reproduzco. Pero lo que quiero es llamar uno por uno a las canciones no a todas, asi desde otra activity llamar a las demas canciones.

Les dejo mi codigo para que me puedan ayudar..

```
ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp;

int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lista);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        list.add(fields[i].getName());
    }


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, list);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(mp != null ){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }                                                                                   



            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resID);
            mp.start();
            play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public void play_pause(View view){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

ahora inclui el metodo idAudio pero no me funciona, me salta error "android resurce linking failed". que estoy haciendo mal?

```
ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp;

int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_album1);

    play_pause = findViewById(R.id.play);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lista);

    list = new ArrayList<>();


    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        list.add(fields[i].getName());


        int idAudio = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(album1.this, idAudio);
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item_lista, list);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();

        }

            try {
                //Obtiene el id del audio seleccionado.

                int idAudio = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(posicion), "raw", getPackageName());

                final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), idAudio);
                player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        //Ready to play!
                        player.start();
                    }
                });
                //Prepare player
                player.prepare();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException iee) {
                iee.printStackTrace();
            }}

        });
}
}


public void play_pause(View view){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si en el `ArrayList` llamado `lista` contienes los audios almacenados en `/raw`, puedes obtener el id del audio de esta forma para reproducirlo mediante el `MediaPlayer`:

```
   int idAudio = this.getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(<indice elemento en lista>), "raw", this.getPackageName());
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, idAudio);
```

ahora para obtener el indice del elemento en el listado el cual seleccionaste en el `ListView`, puedes realizarlo mediante el parámetro `position`

```
    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            try {
                //Obtiene el id del audio seleccionado.
                int idAudio = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(position), "raw", getPackageName());

                final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), idAudio);
                player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        //Ready to play!
                        player.start();
                    }
                });
                //Prepare player
                player.prepare();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException iee) {
                iee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: pero como hago para seleccionar mas de dos canciones y ponerlo en mi listview?  porque con el parametro de position solo obtendre una sola cancion o estoy confundido?

Comment: ahora combine mi anterior codigo con lo que me recomendaste pero me sale error.. que puedo hacer?